# Famo.us fit parent size

Tags: famo.us

Not providing any size for a surface will make the surface taking the size of it's parent, for an image we call this a "fill".

[image]

But this distord the image, now how to make a surface (or whatever element with a size) to fit it's parent height or width keeping the elements ratio ?

Minimal code example:

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    var firstSurface = new Surface({
        size: [200, 100],
        content: 'How to make this surface fit its parent (mainContext) keeping the 2/1 size ratio ?',
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: 'orange'
        }
    });

    mainContext.add(firstSurface);
```

Comment: Do you have code sample?

Comment: @HP. I added a code example, my intuition tells me we should be using a ContextualView to get the parent's size and then adapt the size of the surface accordingly.

Comment: Have you try `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to calculate? Assuming the parent size is the window. Otherwise, use `Modifier` to define the **known** parent size and another `Modifier` within it for the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sizeFrom method on Modifier. The 'from' functions of Modifier are very useful in that you do not need to worry about binding to the engine resize event. Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve..

Hope this helps!

```
var Engine   = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface  = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
var firstSurface = new Surface({
    size: [undefined, undefined],
    content: 'How to make this surface fit its parent (mainContext) keeping the 2/1 size ratio ?',
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }
});

firstSurface.mod = new Modifier({ origin: [0.5,0.5] });

firstSurface.mod.sizeFrom(function(){

    ratio         = (2.0/1.0) ;
    contextSize   = mainContext.getSize() ;
    contextRatio  = contextSize[0] / contextSize[1] ;

    width = ratio > contextRatio ? contextSize[0] : contextSize[1] * ratio ;
    height = width / ratio ;
    return [width,height] ;
});

mainContext.add(firstSurface.mod).add(firstSurface);
```

Comment: Ok let's take this as the best current solution, perhaps there will be "one day" a dedicated object achieving this task.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will scale the image's width while preserve the aspect ratio. No modifiers are necessary, just clever CSS. Scaling by the height is similar.

```
var image = new ImageSurface({
    content : 'path/to/your/image/',
    size : [undefined, true],
    properties : {
        width : '100%'
    }
});
```

Explanation:

- (1) having a `true` value in the size means "use the value calculated by the DOM"
- (2) having an `undefined` value in the size means "use my parent's value"
- (3) having the CSS `width : 100%` will allow the DOM to scale the height as the width changes according to the image's default aspect ratio.

Putting it together means:

get the width of my parent (2) → scale the height according to the aspect ratio (3) → use the height calculated by the DOM as my actual height (1)

Comment: Hey david! This is much simpler looking, but does not address a window with aspect ratio larger than the image. There is never a point where the height is the constraint and the width varies.

Comment: At that point there are two options: (1) if distortion of the image is okay, add a `minHeight : 100%` CSS property. This will stretch the image to fill the height. (2) dynamically change between a width-based approach (above) and a height-based approach (not shown, but should be clear from above) when the aspect ratio flips from > 1 to < 1 or vice versa. This will cause some part of the image to be cropped by the viewport. Unfortunately a solution that doesn't stretch or crop the image is impossible.

Comment: Mine works if you know the aspect ratio, which in the question, was just 2:1. I guess this is not always the case though!

Comment: Yep, your approach works, but only if you have access to the parent size. There are instances where this isn't always the case, however. Commonly, parent views have access to their children views, but children views should rarely need to know about their parent.

Answer (score 2):

This article describes the the sizing-modes of ImageSurface and BkImageSurface:

http://famousco.de/2014/07/depth-look-images-sizing-modes/